# QGIS setSuppress function in python

Tags: pyqgis, typeerror

I am trying to call the [setSuppress function](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsEditFormConfig.html#acbb549bcea0d2daa2ced3accd1d576f2)

I want to set the suppress to `2=SuppressOff` by writing in Python Console `QgsEditFormConfig.setSuppress(2)` but I am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: QgsEditFormConfig.setSuppress(QgsEditFormConfig.FeatureFormSuppress): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QgsEditFormConfig'
```

Does anyone know the right syntax for that the `setSuppress` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct syntax would be:

```
QgsEditFormConfig().setSuppress(2)
```

or

```
QgsEditFormConfig().setSuppress(QgsEditFormConfig.SuppressOff)
```

But for me, neither of these work as the `suppress` value doesn't seem to be saved which can be checked using:

```
QgsEditFormConfig().suppress()
```

The value is always `0`.

---

But if you want to suppress the feature form for a specific layer, you could use:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.editFormConfig().setSuppress(1)
```

Or you could directly change the setting in the menubar `Settings > Options > Digitizing` using:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue("/Qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog", True)
```

Comment: @Spyros - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)